# Does reusing symbols improve SVG performance?

Tags: performance, svg, visualization

Assuming a relatively modern, SVG-supporting desktop browser and an SVG consisting of hundreds of similar, simple nodes:

1. The document could be set up as many individual shape elements (`<circle>`, `<line>`, etc.) with their own attributes defined.
2. The document could be set up as a few `<symbol>` elements and many individual `<use>` instances that place them and size them appropriately ([W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement)).

I understand the semantic and code-maintenance reasons to use `<symbols>`/`<use>`, but I'm not concerned with those now, I'm strictly trying to optimize rendering, transformation and DOM update performance.  I could see `<symbol>` working similar to reusing sprites in Flash, conserving memory and being generally a good practice.  However, I'd be surprised if browser vendors have been thinking this way (and this isn't really the *intent* of the feature).

*Edit: I am not expecting the base symbols to be changed or added to over the life-cycle of the SVG, only the instance locations, sizes, etc*

- Are there any clear patterns to `<symbol>`/`<use>` performance?
- How idiosyncratic is it to individual browser implementations?
- Are there differences between reusing `<symbol>` vs `<g>` vs nested `<svg>`?

Answer (score 17):

[Rohit Kalkur](https://github.com/rovolution) compared rendering speed of the creation of 5000 SVG symbols using `use` against directly creating the SVG symbol's shapes, see [here](http://slides.com/rovolutionary/tuning-svg-performance-in-a-production-app#/14). It turns out that rendering `SVG` shapes using `use` was almost **50%** slower. He reasons that:

> The use element takes nodes from within the SVG document, and
>   duplicates them in a non-exposed DOM

Given this, I assume that using SVG `symbol`s is at best as performant as manually creating the `symbols`s shape.

Comment: Is this still the case? Is there any point of using `<use/>` at all, say, for `<paths/>`?

Comment: If you have very complex graphics and use them often than it might make sense to use symbols via an external file as the external file will be loaded only once and can easily be cached. For example, normally icons don't change often but content does, i.e., an external SVG has better cache properties than direct inclusion in your HTML.

Comment: For what it's worth, out experience was totally the opposite. Cca. year 2020, we replaced independent (but identical) embedded `<svg>` tags with one `<symbol>` and many `<use>` tags, which increased the performance greatly. In our file-explorer-like UI, rendering hundreds of files was lowered from something like 5-10 seconds to less than a second (sorry, I don't have the exact benchmarking timings anymore). I think that anyone reading this today should not take the above answer for granted and should perform their own performance investigation...

Answer (score 9):

I would advise you to not nest <use> elements deeply. That is known to cause slowdowns in most browsers, see [here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/2011Feb/0056.html) and [here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/2011Feb/0051.html).

In the general case though it should be fast, at least as long as the template itself isn't changed much (since if you do then each of the instances need to be updated too, and each of them can differ from the rest due to CSS inheritance).

Between <svg> and <symbol> there isn't that big of a difference on a functional level, they both allow you to define a coordinate system (via the 'viewBox' attribute). A <g> element doesn't let you do that. Note that <symbol> elements are invisible unless referenced by a <use>, whereas <svg> and <g> are both visible per default. However, in most cases it's advisable to make the template be a child of a <defs> element.

Comment: Good tip on nesting - I can see why that would be expensive to render with the multiple hierarchies of the DOM, CSS, symbolic references...

Answer (score 3):

If you change the contents of a g or svg element then a UI can look at the area the old contents were drawn in and where the update will be drawn to and simply redraw those two areas, even redraw only once if they are the same e.g. changing the colour of a shape.

If you update the contents of a symbol then all the instances must be redrawn. It's harder  to do that by calculating for each instance where the old and new parts to redraw are as the areas may be affected by transforms and simpler to just redraw all parts of all instances. Some browsers may do the former and some the latter.

In either case, a UI must at a minimum track the changes in the symbol and propagate those changes to all the instances. That's more than likely to have some overhead.

Of course, if you're just moving individual symbol instances and the contents are static then no tracking is required and performance is likely to be similar.

Comment: Good point.  In the scenarios I am imagining, the symbols would not change or be added to over the life-cycle of the SVG, only the instances - I edited the question to clarify that rather important point.