# Does using <defs> reduce page weight when including reusing multiple SVGs?

Tags: svg, web-performance

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs

> SVG allows graphical objects to be defined for later reuse. It is
>   recommended that, wherever possible, referenced elements be defined
>   inside of a `<defs>` element. Objects created inside a `<defs>` element
>   are not rendered immediately; instead, think of them as templates or
>   macros created for future use.
>
> Defining these elements inside of a `<defs>` element promotes
>   understandability of the SVG content and thus promotes accessibility.
>   You can use a `<use>` element to render those elements wherever you want
>   in the viewport.

Does using this technique influence page weight/size in any way?

Comment: It would be good if you quote the relevant stuff from that link. Otherwise the question will become meaningless if the link goes bad.

Comment: please define "page weight"

Comment: This may be helpful: [Does reusing symbols improve SVG performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604999/does-reusing-symbols-improve-svg-performance)